# What is this accent?

Tags: accent

I stumbled upon [this](http://youtu.be/-6611nIAew0) YouTube video, and I really like the accent of the speaker. How is his accent called?
I'm not British, but I'm quite sure it isn't the "standard" British accent (e.g. the one you would hear on BBC); it seems thicker, but I don't know which region or class it is typical of.

Comment: I can't place this accent, it sounds fairly neutral to me. I can tell you he is not northern because he has a long 'a' in 'bathroom' (barthroom) and this is more typical of a midland/southern accent. He also mentions 'Banbury Road'. Banbury is a town in [Northamptonshire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northamptonshire). I know he only gives it as an example but perhaps he chose it because he lives there.

Comment: I agree with @Mynamite that it's a fairly "neutral" educated RP accent. To the extent that we could place the guy's (somewhat disguised) *regional* accent, it's reminiscent of Somerset / Wiltshire / Gloucester to me - but he could be from Devon or Dorset, or maybe it's further East (rural Hampshire or Berkshire). And for the record, it's *exactly* the kind of accent the BBC likes to promote - just a faint trace of dialectal origins, and very little of that plummy upper-class "Queen's English" they used to use all the time.

Comment: In another, [related, video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeWloCtb-hc), the tutor says he was born in Oxford, attended Cambridge University, and has a 'Standard Southern British' accent. And Banbury is a market town and civil parish on the River Cherwell in the Cherwell District of **Oxfordshire** [Wikipedia]. I used to change trains there when at university.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And Oxford is less than 30 miles from Banbury. Just call me Sherlock :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is about the English language, not about the identification of regional accents. Furthermore any question should be understandable here. Until one can post sound clips links to external videos are off limits.